# Inquiry about about OUTER JOINS in SQL

Tags: sql, database, rdbms, relation

In sql, if we have the following relations :

- `A(B,C)` with values `{ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) }`
- `D(B,E)` with values `{ (1,2), (3,4), (7,8), (9,10) }`

Would the resulting table be `BCE` with values `{ (1,2,2), (3,4,4), (5,6,null), (7,null,8), (9,null,10) }` for the operation:

```
SELECT * FROM A NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN D
```

Also what would happen in the case of `natural left outer join` and `natural right outer join`?

Comment: Why don't you run those queries and find out for yourself?

Comment: I tried, got error 
select * FROM (R NATURAL OUTER JOIN S)
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "NATURAL" was found following "select * FROM (R
".  Expected tokens may include:  "<table_expr>".  SQLSTATE=42601
db2 => R NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN S

Comment: You get an error because your query is wrong. It should NOT be `select * FROM (R NATURAL OUTER JOIN S) SQL0104N'`, instead use `select * FROM R NATURAL OUTER JOIN S`, without '(' and ')'

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes DBMS (including version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (including input) & diffable expected output. Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Please always check the manual when you have problems with relatively new syntax.

Comment: Forget about the NATURAL JOIN construction! Specify the JOIN conditions!

Answer (score 0):

You can test these things easily using one of the many online database query interfaces, like SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bc42d/1